# Pie chart ( Python reportLab): Font Size of the labels

Tags: python, label, size, reportlab

I am trying to increase the size of labels in a pie chart. Using Reportlab in Python.

```
    pc.y = 500
    pc.width = 700
    pc.height = 700
    pc.data = datos
    pc.labels = etiquetas
    pc.sideLabels=True
    pc.simpleLabels=False
    pc.checkLabelOverlap= True
    # pc.slices.fontSize = 14 This is not working ¿Any idea?
    pc.slices.labelRadius = 1.75
    d.add(pc)
```

I suppose that it's something like **pc.slices.fontSize = 14** but I don't find the correct attribute.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

solved: pc.slices.fontSize = ...